# How to clone a VM to a specific Datastore?

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere, pysphere, pyvmomi

I would like to use pyvmomi to clone VMs and attach it to specific datastore (specifically with most free space).

I couldn't find a solution for this in pysphere therefore I trying luck with pyvmomi but the it seems that learning curve for this library is a bit steeper.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

pyvmomi gives you access to everything in the [VMware vSphere API Reference Documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fright-pane.html). This includes all the methods for cloning VMs from templates and specifying the datastore. Specifically take a look at [VirtualMachineRelocateSpec](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.vm.RelocateSpec.html#field_detail) which is a parameter to RelocateVM_Task (the method you will need to clone the VM).